# How the redirect_to parameter is added to wp_login.php when trying to access wp-admin?

Tags: theme-development

I have noticed that a `redirect_to` parameter is added to `wp-login.php` URL when trying to access `wp-admin`, so from where does it come?
I have tried to search into the wp-admin folder but lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect parameter is created at `auth_redirect` function:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1064

and it is added at `wp_login_url` function:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L328